# How do I make multiple rows out of my ngFor Data?

Tags: html, angular

In looping through my data, I'd like to have the "app-system" components displayed in even rows across the screen.  When I try to put it in a table and then in a row, of course it only creates one row rather than multiple rows with the data.

Here's an image of what its doing currently https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUOIQ.jpg
I have to scroll down to see all 190 items in the row.

I've thought about creating another ngFor loop of rows to apply to the data, but I can't quite figure out how. I'm unable to apply the answers I've tried to research to my project due to my lack of experience.

Here's my template that grabs my "app-system" component and loops through all of the data. It currently shows in one LONG row down the page:

Here is the template for the app-system component that is being copied over, the buttons need to be split into seperate rows. The popup box opens when you click one of the buttons.

````
<div class="section-container">
<div class="section-container">
  <table>
    <div *ngFor="let system of systemList  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 190, 
         currentPage: p }; let i = index">
         <app-system [systemInput]="system"></app-system>
      </div>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination section-container card-deck">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls> 
</div>
</div>

```<div class='card mb-1 shadow button-background'>
  <div class= "popup-box">
    <popup #popup>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.AMStatus; else showAMInvalid"> Anti-Malware Version: Current</p>
      <ng-template #showAMInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Anti-Malware Version: Needs Update</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.BLStatus; else showBLInvalid">Bitlocker Status: Active</p>
      <ng-template #showBLInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Bitlocker Status: Inactive</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.FirewallRullStatus; else showFirewallRuleInvalid"> Firewall Rules: Applied</p>
      <ng-template #showFirewallRuleInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Firewall Rules: Not Applied</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.FirewallContentStatus; else showFirewallContentInvalid"> Firewall: Enabled </p>
      <ng-template #showFirewallContentInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Firewall Status: Disabled</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.SCCMStatus; else showSCCMStatusInvalid"> SCCM Status: Running</p>
      <ng-template #showSCCMStatusInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">SCCM Status: Not Running</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.MSBaselineStatus; else showMSBaselineInvalid"> Microsoft Standards: Met</p>
      <ng-template #showMSBaselineInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Microsoft Standards: Not Met</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="dateCheck() == true; else showDateInvalid"> Last Update: {{systemInput.UpdatedDate | date}}</p>
      <ng-template #showDateInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Last Update: {{systemInput.UpdatedDate | date}}</p>
      </ng-template>
      <p *ngIf="systemInput.USBStatus; else showUSBInvalid">Removable Storage: Disabled</p>
      <ng-template #showUSBInvalid>
      <p style="background-color:yellow; ">Removable Storage: Enabled</p>
      </ng-template>

    </popup>
  </div>
  <button (click)="ClickButton()" [ngClass]="{
    'btn buttonGood':isValid(),
    'btn buttonDateAlert':isValid()=='datewarning',
    'btn buttonAlert':isValid()==false
  }">{{systemInput.hostname}}</button>
</div>
````

```
    export interface Ipcidata {
        id: Int16Array;
        hostname: string;
        AMStatus: boolean;
        BLStatus: boolean;
        FirewallRullStatus: boolean;
        FirewallContentStatus: boolean;
        SCCMStatus: boolean;
        MSBaselineStatus: boolean;
        UpdatedDate: Date;
        USBStatus: boolean;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want them to appear in separate rows. Is that right?

Comment: Is stystemList an array? Can you post what the object looks like your trying to loop through?

Comment: @Ajmal Yeah thats basically all i'm trying to do.

-

The system component is looping through an object / array of data I'm getting from my database.  All that I need to do is show rows of these buttons (shown in my image), one is generated for each object in the database that is made, and when clicked they pop up with the actual data. 

So really I just need these buttons to show in separate rows rather than the one that they are currently in, which makes it so I have to scroll down 180 items to see them all.

Comment: Show us an example of what systemList is since " object / array " doesn't give much definition to what you're trying to feed it.

Comment: You're saying row, but you're thinking of column.

You should use flex/grid for that.

Comment: @ChrisW.  Sorry about that! I was trying to respond on my phone at work. I've added the interface that is pushed into the systemList property, as well as the template for APP-SYSTEM.   

I'm just iterating over a button that has a popup that uses the systemList array for its data inside the popup.  Thanks for your patience, I know I'm probably just missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying row, but you're thinking of column. You should use flex/grid for that.
You should do what you're trying with css.

On container element do:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px; // Or whatever
  height: 500px; // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm an idiot and was working on this way too late. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `<div>` to a `<tr>` element

```
<div class="section-container">
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let system of systemList  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 190, 
         currentPage: p }; let i = index">
         <app-system [systemInput]="system"></app-system>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <div class="pagination section-container card-deck">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and it still seems to put all of the objects in the same row.

Comment: Is your systemList an array? I don't see why this wouldn't iterate over the object unless the systemList is not actually an array.

Comment: Would help to have some definition as to whether it's an array of objects, or if OP is expected they keys in a single object to iterate the ngFor?

Comment: Sorry! I'm pushing the IPCI data array into a system list property. The APP-SYSTEM component uses that property in a popup box inside of a button.  The button and the data within is being properly iterated over, but it's displaying ONE row of buttons rather than even rows across the screen. I know the solution is probably extremely simple, but I've searched and it's probably just something I've done wrong.  I've added the template and interface code above.  

SystemList = any, just a property to hold my interface.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is `ngIf`

```
<div class="section-container">
  <table>
    <div *ngFor="let system of systemList  | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 190, 
         currentPage: p }; let i = index">
         <app-system *ngIf="i % 2 == 0" [systemInput]="system"></app-system>
      </div>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination section-container card-deck">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls> 
</div>
</div>
```

All we do is use a modulus expression to only show the even rows (The inverse would be `i % 2 != 0`)

app-system is a child element however, so there will be empty parent divs...

Comment: Thank you, I thought this would work as well and tried this after searching a few answers, but for whatever reason the buttons are still just displaying in a single row.

Comment: @st0rch1991 if that doesn't work... Something else is happening. Try moving a copy of the code to StackBlitz and referencing it here... Otherwise it's a shot in the dark.